# ModelForm has no model class specified error django framework

Tags: python, django

I'm receiving the error

```
"ValueError at /accounts/create/
ModelForm has no model class specified."
```

Views.py:

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from .forms import CustomUserCreationForm
from .models import CustomUser
from django.contrib.auth.models import Group

def signupView(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = CustomUserCreationForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            username = form.cleaned_data.get('username')
            signup_user = CustomUser.objects.get(username=username)
            customer_group = Group.objects.get(name='Customer')
            customer_group.user_set.add(signup_user)

    else:
        form = CustomUserCreationForm()
    return render(request, 'signup.html', {'form':form})
```

I can't find any the error for the life of me, any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Edit::

forms.py

```
from django import forms
from django.contrib.auth.forms import UserCreationForm, UserChangeForm

from .models import CustomUser


class CustomUserCreationForm(UserCreationForm):

    class Meta(UserCreationForm):
        Meta = CustomUser
        fields = UserCreationForm.Meta.fields + ('age',)

class CustomUserChangeForm(UserChangeForm):

    class Meta:
        model = CustomUser
        fields = UserChangeForm.Meta.fields
```

Above is the CustomUserCreationForm

Comment: Please show `CustomUserCreationForm`, the error suggests that you haven't added `model = CustomUser` to this form's `Meta`

Comment: from django import forms
from django.contrib.auth.forms import UserCreationForm, UserChangeForm

from .models import CustomUser


class CustomUserCreationForm(UserCreationForm):

    class Meta(UserCreationForm):
        Meta = CustomUser
        fields = UserCreationForm.Meta.fields + ('age',)

class CustomUserChangeForm(UserChangeForm):

    class Meta:
        model = CustomUser
        fields = UserChangeForm.Meta.fields

Comment: Can you share your model? There's some error in `Meta` class. Mostly you have used `Model=CustomUser`

Comment: You have set `Meta = CustomUser`, you need to use `model = CustomUser` instead

Comment: Thanks very much guys, your answers worked perfectly !

Answer (score 0):

In your `CustomUser` model, in `Meta` class, you have used `Model = CustomUser`. Instead you need to use `model = CustomUser`.